# How to import CDN scripts into a web component?

Tags: web-component, shadow-dom, native-web-component

Here is a simple code of web component I tried to had inside a summernote.js :
This is just an example of using js files of components and using them inside a web component, but for some reason its not working at all. Like the script is not being loaded inside the DOM or its there but can't be used. I alo tried this without shadow dom and got the same result. What am I missing?

```
class MyEditor extends HTMLElement {
    constructor() {
        super();
        this.attachShadow({ mode: 'open' });
        this.isOpen = false;
        this.shadowRoot.innerHTML = `
            <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.4.1.slim.min.js"></script>
            <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/summernote@0.8.18/dist/summernote-lite.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
            <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/summernote@0.8.18/dist/summernote-lite.min.js"></script>
            
        <style>
            
        </style>
        
        <div id="summernote">
            <span style="color:red;background-color: yellow;">example</span>
        </div>
    `;

        const summernote = this.shadowRoot.querySelectorAll('#summernote');
        summernote.summernote({
            placeholder: 'Hello stand alone ui',
            tabsize: 2,
            height: 600,
            toolbar: [
                ['style', ['style']],
                ['font', ['bold', 'underline', 'clear']],
                ['color', ['color']],
                ['para', ['ul', 'ol', 'paragraph']],
                ['table', ['table']],
                ['insert', ['link', 'picture', 'video']],
                ['view', ['fullscreen', 'codeview', 'help']]
            ],
            disableResizeEditor: true
        });
}

customElements.define('my-editor', MyEditor);
```

None of the import Files is loaded, so nothing can't be used. How to solve this issue?

BTW, a static html page its working:

```
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>without bootstrap</title>

    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.4.1.slim.min.js"></script>
    <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/summernote@0.8.18/dist/summernote-lite.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/summernote@0.8.18/dist/summernote-lite.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>

    <div id="summernote">
        <span style="color:red;background-color: yellow;">1234</span>
    </div>

<script>
    $('#summernote').summernote({
        placeholder: 'Hello stand alone ui',
        tabsize: 2,
        height: 600,
        toolbar: [
            ['style', ['style']],
            ['font', ['bold', 'underline', 'clear']],
            ['color', ['color']],
            ['para', ['ul', 'ol', 'paragraph']],
            ['table', ['table']],
            ['insert', ['link', 'picture', 'video']],
            ['view', ['fullscreen', 'codeview', 'help']]
        ],
        disableResizeEditor: true
    });

</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Please add an [Minimal minimal-reproducible-example StackOverflow Snippet](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) to your post. It will help readers execute your code with one click. And help create answers with one click. See [How to add a StackOverflow snippet](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/269753/feedback-requested-runnable-code-snippets-in-questions-and-answers)

Comment: And doublecheck with the creators they actually support shadowDOM: https://github.com/summernote/summernote/issues Note: It isn't a well supported editor, original creators have left

Answer (score 0):

InnerHTML doesn't parse script tag.

`index.html`

```
<template id="test_template">
        <h1>Template script function</h1>
        <script src="./test.js"></script>
    </template>
```

`test.js`

```
console.log({ current_time: Date.now() });
```

`my-script.js`

```
const testTemplate = document.getElementById("test_template");
const testContent = testTemplate.content.cloneNode(true);
document.body.appendChild(testContent);
```